# API's to access 'Novell GroupWise' data for c#.What will be difference if i use "gwtapp.dll" or "GroupWise Web Services"?

Tags: c#, api, groupwise

I want to read mail,calendar,contact items from Novell GroupWise Client.(using version 8).
How to start with? Which API is best for this?

What will be difference if i use "gwtapp.dll" or "GroupWise Web Services" ?

thanx

Answer (score 2):

One good way would be to use GroupWise Web Services provided by NDK. Have a look at the [Novell documentation for the web services](http://developer.novell.com/documentation/gwsoap/index.html).