# Java GroupWise Mail Client

Tags: java, outlook-2003, groupwise

Is anyone aware of a way to retrieve and send mails by talking directly to the GroupWise server.

I want to be able to retrieve mail using Java if possible.

I wrote a Outlook Plug-In that retrieved mail out of GroupWise via the Groupwise Outloop Plug-in *(If that makes sense)*.

Then dropped the message in a directory where I retrieved it with a Java App.

The problem is that I cannot add more than one GroupWise account in Outlook and need to.

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934273/apis-to-access-novell-groupwise-data-for-c-what-will-be-difference-if-i-use) question, but would like to know if there is a Java API
 that will allow me to retrieve/send mail from the GroupWise server in a JavaMail like manner.

Thanks.

Comment: I also found you can add Proxies with the GroupWise Outlook mail Plug-In.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GroupWise allows mails to be retrieved using IMAP and POP3 which are standard supported by JavaMail. (And outlook too for that matter)

Sending mail should also be possible using smtp.

If it is for plain email I prefer to use these basic proptocols like smtp, pop3 and imap because they work almost everywhere, anytime and on any platform. They are less feature rich than the proprietary protocols, but that point is often not very relevant since many of these features are only meaningful for a subset of the mailclients out there.

Comment: Just a note: POP3 and IMAP4 is not enabled by default on GroupWise server 8.